# After angular.bootstrap in ts file the angularjs not rendering anything on the browser showing empty page

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular

Well by following guide from one tutorial and [https://angular.io/guide/upgrade](http://angular.io/guide/upgrade)
I manage to make angularjs bootstrap by using this

```
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp'], { strictDi: true });
```

i am working on mvc dotnet web application 
**problem** is that after putting that code in **app.module.ts** file and removing ng-app from html index page.
nothing is loading on the page. empty page. nothing load from angularjs directive and angularjs file. 
help me to figure out this. 
Thanks in advance 


After this i will upgrade angularjs to angular 4 after making this bootstrap

Comment: are you compiling your typescript file? as mentioned in https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#switching-to-typescript

Comment: I am only compiling app.module file to remove ng app from html and make the app angularbootstrap

Comment: Are you following steps mentioned in above link?

Comment: issue resolved 
i didn't includes some nuget packages so this was the problem after upgrading some jquery version and adding new package its working fine now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`app.module.ts` is Angular 2+ related but

```
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp'], { strictDi: true });
```

is AngularJs related

so you can't combine the 2 methods

there is no straight way to upgrade from agnularjs to angular because angularjs is mvc ES5 framework but angular is component oriented ES6 framewok

Comment: I found a tutorial which upgrading from angularjs to angular by making bootstrapping hybrid. which also mention in documentation of angular 
https://angular.io/guide/upgrade